# Why is a Control Character Null getting added to the end of my .js file?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add, jquery and bootstrap, javascript files in my html code and when I run the page and use devtools I get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token, on all my js files.

They all have a control character null added at the end and I don't understand why it is happening. I declared them like this.

```
<script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where do you add this code in your file? maybe you have unended tag or missing some characters which leads to this problem!

Comment: I have it inside the head tag like so,<!DOCTYPE html>

  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="icon" href="logo.png" >
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: That control character must be in the files on the server, they're not added here.

Comment: Try to download them and use them locally and fix any problem they have